# Show text only to the author of the article

Tags: author

How can I be displayed in an article written by a writer in a text format only to the same author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a conclusion !

```
if ($current_user->ID == $post->post_author)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust following code in your theme files

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
    echo 'YOUR TEXT FOR AUTHOR OF POST GOES HERE...!';
}
```